# Ruby Multithreading: making one thread wait for a signal from another

Tags: ruby, multithreading

In Ruby, I want to have two threads running at the same time, and want the background thread to periodically signal the foreground thread. How do I get the foreground thread to block until the background thread says 'go'? I can think of a few ways to do it, but am after the most appropriate, idiomatic Ruby method.

In code:

```
loop do  # background, thread 1
  sleep 3
  receive_input
  tell_foreground_input_is_ready # <-- how do I do this?
end
```

and

```
loop do  # foreground, thread 2
  wait_for_signal_from_background  # <-- how do I do this?
  do_something
end
```

(note: background may signal multiple times to the foreground. each time foreground finishes waiting, it resets backlog.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this works quite nicely:

```
require 'thread'
queue = Queue.new
Thread.new do
  100.times do |i|
    sleep 1
    queue.enq i
  end
end

loop do
  print "waiting... "
  puts queue.deq      # this function blocks.
end
```

Comment: In MRI ("C" ruby versions 1.8.6 or 1.9.2) this will work, as there's a giant big lock around all ruby code, so even though you have 2 threads, only one can ever run at a time... In JRuby or IronRuby however, the threads will run simultaneously, and the code won't be safe. You'll need to use `Mutex` and `ConditionVariable` to manage this

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use conditional variables and mutexes, as per [this page](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an clean and brief implementation: http://emptysqua.re/blog/an-event-synchronization-primitive-for-ruby/